# How to print in linux? I have a Canon PIXMA iP3600 connected to my USB0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, centos

When I type `lsusb` I can see the USB is showing as connected to Canon. However when I do `lpr print.pdf` it doesn't print anything at all.

How can I fix it so that I can print using the command `lpr`?

Comment: You will need to define/setup the printer on your system. Which version of Linux are you actually running as your tags mention three different types

Comment: @Linker3000: Fedora 15 is base. And virtual box i am using Ubuntu (Seamless mode) + CentOS (resize mode) + FreeBSD (resize mode). But none can detect.

Comment: Did you tried to use CUPS???   http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/overview.html

Comment: Indeed, CUPS is probably all you need.

Comment: [There was a discussion over the Canon Pixma iP3600 - Apparently Canon has released CUPS drivers.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=948312).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use [CUPS](http://cups.org) to manage printer, driver and documents, if something wrong continues to happend, so you would investigate for specific problems (such as printer device, printer driver, or even if your linux is sending the correct parameters for your printer).

I hope CUPS will solve your problem.
Good look, and dot forget to post yor results here :D